Who invented the warp coil?
In Star Trek, the FTL method of travel employed by humans is warp drive.
This is made possible by two major components:

A huge power supply; in this case, so closely linked that it's often simply referred to as the warp core, however, this is just the power supply.
Warp coils; this device actually generates the subspace warp field.

It is well documented that item #1 was invented by Zefram Cochrane and eventually improved upon by Henry Archer, to the point where Earth had a reactor/core powerful enough to achieve warp 5, and the ship it was installed on became the first of many ships to be named Enterprise.
However, while the history of the reactor/core is documented, I can't find any details on who was the brains behind the warp coils, without which Cochrane wouldn't have achieved the warp flight which initiated first contact. He'd probably still be a legendary name as the person who invented an incredible new energy source. That would still have changed humanity, but without the coils, Starfleet — and, by extension, Star Trek — wouldn't have happened.

You are mistaken. Cochrane invented the Warp coil and powered it with a nuclear core. Others "invented" the warp core, but humans didn't get access to it until after First Contact, so presumably it was shared with us by the Vulcans, who may or may not have invented it

There's also the added wrinkle that human FTL flight is heavily based on reverse-engineered Vulcan tech, so it's possible that some or even none of Cochrane's designs made it into Henry Archer's "Warp Five Engine".

Larry Warp and Serge Coil?

I've very tempted to close this as a dupe of How did Cochrane obtain dilithium for the first warp flight?

In the real world scientific advances are small. Consider special relativity Einstein got pre-existing math and pre-existing observations to work together in a single model.  Likewise if there was a realistic fictional history of warp drive there would be prior awareness of subspace fields and some ceramic that made them.  The discovery is getting them to move your ship forward.  But I'm not going to claim that realistic fiction exists.  The novel Federation mentioned inertial dampeners were invented for roller coasters.  It might have covered coils before FC ruined the franchise

Also, NX-01 was not "the first of many ships named Enterprise".  Many ships predated that and semi-canonically the NX-01 is named after the OV-101 Enterprise ("Space Shuttle") which IRL was named after the fictional NCC-1701 Enterprise.  Go figure.

The naval carrier USS Enterprise was only 5 years old when Star Trek first aired

And even that wasn't the first American naval ship to have the name
